# Clipboard (cut/copy) is not working in Mozilla Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, clipboard, clipboard.js

I used the clipboard.js plugin, but it's not working in Mozilla Firefox. When I tried to copy the Mozilla browser, this shows the below warning message.

> "mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run
>   very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial
>   [[Prototype]] value using Object.create"

but this is working correctly in chrome.

My mozilla browser version is 43.0b3.

How to clipboard is working in Mozilla Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

This message is just a warning that comes from ES6 to ES5 transpilation. If you're experiencing different behaviors on Firefox, please share a code snippet so we can help you better.